# Cannot load sqlite.dll with QSQLITE2 Qt plugin

Tags: qt, sqlite, dll, qmake, qsqldatabase

I use QtCreator + mingw.

I have compiled QSQLITE2 plugin. I simply entered plugin directory in Qt source code:

`c:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\sqlite`

and I built it with my sqlite 2.8.17 that I have locally (as dll and header):

`qmake "LIBS+=-Lc:\projects\lib -lsqlite" "INCLUDEPATH+=c:\projects\include"`
`make`
`make install`

Everything builds okay.

Now, I have another DLL (also implemented as Qt plugin, a custom one), which makes use of QSQLITE2 Qt plugin. My own dll is also linked to sqlite.dll. So it looks like this:

```
my.dll                       depends on sqlite.dll
%QT_PLUGINS%\qsqlite2d.dll   depends on sqlite.dll
my.dll                       uses qsqlite2d.dll through Qt's plugin engine
myApp.exe                    loads my.dll
```

Problem is that my application cannot load my.dll, because of `invalid location access` or something like that. I don't know any details and that's the problem.

The `sqlite.dll` is in the application directory when running it.

When I run application in debug mode, it crashes in some assembly file, but in stack trace I can see that it's somewhere inside sqlite.dll, in sqlite_step symbol. That's all I know.

Note 1) I have another plugin dll, the `my3.dll`, which uses QSQLITE plugin (it's for sqlite3) and is linked with `sqlite3.dll` and this one loads just fine. I have compiled QSQLITE plugin myself as well (even there was the one provided with Qt, that's because Qt linked statically to sqlite3 and I wanted it to link dynamically to `sqlite3.dll`).

Note 2) Both plugins work just fine under Linux.

Any hints what might be wrong? What else can I check?

**EDIT:**

I've just performed a test: I deleted `my.dll` from plugins to avoid loading it at all. Then I added code to `main.cpp`:

```
    QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE2", ":memory:");
```

Thing is, that it also crashed, with the very same stack trace (at this very line, I debugged it). Thus I think there's something wrong with sqlite2 Qt plugin, but I'm still unable to tell what. I looked up for other `sqlite.dll`, I just downloaded the one from sqlite.org: http://www.sqlite.org/sqlitedll-2_8_17.zip - so it's official build, but it's the exactly the same file I had and it also fails the same way.

Comment: One more note: sqlite.h defines `extern const char sqlite_encoding[]` which is not defined in the sqlite.dll (I could not compile QSQLITE2 plugin), so I have to edit file `qsql_sqlite2.cpp` and add line: `const char sqlite_encoding[] = "UTF-8";` - then Qt plugin compiled correctly. I'm not sure if that's relevant, but just wanted to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that `qsqlite2d.dll` cannot be linked `sqlite.dll`, because `sqlite.dll` is not compiled in debug mode. After recompiling application in release mode (thus using `qsqlite2.dll`, not `qsqlite2d.dll`), the plugin loads correctly and works.

This makes sense, but just one more thing that bugs me - `qsqlited.dll` (for sqlite3) had no problem linking with `sqlite3.dll`. No matter if I compiled debug or release - the single `sqlite3.dll` worked with both debug and release plugins. Anyone has an idea how is that possible? Please comment if you do, I'd appreciate it.